# Truncating a python generator

Tags: python, generator

I would like to know the Pythonic way to write a generator expression that takes the first `n` elements of an infinite generator `g`. Currently, I am doing this:

```
(x for x,_ in zip(g,range(n)))
```

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### `islice`

To wrap [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) in a function would make a lot of sense, the code is much shorter than my alternative below:

```
from itertools import islice

def first_n(iterable, n):
    return islice(iterable, 0, n)
```

and usage:

```
>>> first_n(range(100), 10)
<itertools.islice object at 0xffec1dec>
>>> list(first_n(range(100), 10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

or directly:

```
>>> list(islice(range(100), 0, 10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

### alternative generator

here's an alternative:

```
def first_n(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    for _ in range(n):
        yield next(it)
```

and usage:

```
>>> first_n(range(100), 10)
<generator object first_n at 0xffec73ec>
>>> list(first_n(range(100), 10))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
itertools.islice(g,0,10)
```

should do it?

you might need `list(itertools.islice(g,0,10))`   (since it returns an iterator)

Comment: whoops the iterable argument I had in the wrong spot

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), `itertools.islice` has signature:

```
itertools.islice(iterable, stop)
itertools.islice(iterable, start, stop[, step])
```

So you could use:

```
g2 = itertools.islice(g, 10)


list(g2) == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list(g2) == []  # No elements after the iterable is consumed once
```

(no need to wrap `itertools.islice`, it can be used directly)